# Expression Engine and Safecracker - Problems when uploading an mp3 file

Tags: forms, upload, expressionengine, safecracker

I have 2 mp3 files with sizes 24.7kb and 11mb.

When I try to upload the smaller file, I get no errors.

When I try to upload the bigger file, I get an error. In firebug, I see something like

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://domain.com/application/form/%3C!DOCTYPE%20HTML%3E%3C!--%5Bif....
```

After checking and parsing the string after "form/", it seemed to be the markup of the webpage you are on.

Any idea why this happens?

P.S.

- I have checked my PHP.ini and Expression Engine's file upload preferences and made sure that my maximum file size limit is more than 10mb(used 20mb).
- I am using ExpressionEngine for my framework and Safecracker for my forms
- On Mac, it seems the markup string is shown somewhere in the DOM and you can see it in the page. I don't see it in Firefox or Chrome though

Comment: Despite what your php.ini file might say there may be another one that is over-riding it. I know that with one host I use I can add my own php.ini files but certain parameters in them are ignored in favour of the "master" one. So it could be that there is a file size limit being imposed. It does indeed look like some error page is being generated which is what you are seeing in Firebug. 

Take a look at Tools->Utilities->PHP Info in your EE Controlpanel to see what the real settings are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *probably* still a server issue, rather than something EE specific. I would start by checking the following settings in php.ini (in addition to `upload_max_filesize` which it sounds like you've already bumped up, in roughly the following order:

**`max_execution_time`** sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to run before it is terminated by the parser. I think the most likely candidate is  this one, as it's quite possible that this is being exceeded during the upload or post-upload processing. Default in PHP 5.3 is "30"

**`post_max_size`** (must be greater than upload_max_filesize). Sets max size of post data allowed and also affects file uploads. Default in PHP 5.3 is "128M" but some hosts reduce it considerably.

**`memory_limit`**  sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate. Unlikely to be this one as you'd almost certainly get a PHP error instead, but worth a check for completeness. Default in PHP 5.3 in is "8M"

Answer (score 13):

Something you may wish to check is your XSS setting. Under `Admin` -> `Security and Privacy` -> `Security and Session Preferences`, set the following to `No` and test your upload again:

`Apply XSS Filtering to uploaded files?`

It may have no affect, but I have seen some cases where MP3s and PDFs have caused some very random results due to the XSS filtering; certainly worth ruling out.

Comment: This setting e.g. hint made my day. I was able to upload via a super admin accounts just fine, but member uploads were constantly rejected.